# Flames Logic in PHP

Tags: php, logic

You all must be aware with the flames game logic
http://flamesgame.appspot.com/algorithm..
i am trying to implement this in php.
 where I end up writing this code..
 but for every string i am getting the ans as "S" only.
 unable to figure out whats wrong.
i am stuck with the flames main logic part.
any1 can view any tell were i went wrong?

`

```
    $var1 = "pradeep"; // string1
    $var2 = "neelam"; // string2

    $arr1 = str_split($var1);
    $arr2 = str_split($var2);

/* compairing each elemnt on string1 with string2 */
     for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($var1); $i++) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($var2); $j++)
                    if ($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$j]) {
                        unset($arr1[$i]);
                        unset($arr2[$j]);              
                        break;

                    }
            }

           $result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
         echo count( $result);
         $flame = "flames"; 

/* Flames Main Logic */ 
     for ($i = strlen($flame); $i > 1; $i--) {
                $diff = $result % strlen($flame);
                if ($diff == 0) {
                    $diff = strlen($flame) - 1;
                } else {
                    $diff--;
                }
                $flame[$diff] = "@";
                list($f1, $f2) = preg_split("/@/", $flame);
                $flame = $f2 . $f1;
            }
            switch ($flame) {
                case f:
                    echo "You are now Friends";
                    break;
                case l:
                    echo "You are now Lovers";
                    break;
                case a:
                    echo "You are now Ancestors";
                    break;
                case m:
                    echo "You are now Married";
                    break;
                case e:
                    echo "You are now Enemy";
                    break;
                case s:
                    echo "You are now Sister";
                    break;
            }


    ?>`
```

Comment: Oh dear! We really "all must be aware with the flames game logic"? I am not! What now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$diff = $result % strlen($flame);
```

Code error, use

```
$diff = count($result) % strlen($flame);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using $flame as an array and not a string.

When evaluated as a string you are probably only getting the first element of the $flame array.

```
$flame[$diff] = "@";
```

**This is how I would do this:**

**Processing Time: 70 microseconds.** (0.00007 Sec.)

**I like to write code with no if  else control structures.**

This code is tested.

```
    $flames = str_split(' FLAMES');
    $matrix[6] = array(6,1,2,3,4,5);$matrix[5] = array(5,1,2,3,4);$matrix[4]array(4,1,2,3);$matrix[3] = array(3,1,2);$matrix[2] = array(2,1); 
    $flame = array('Solo','F'=>'Friendship','L'=>'Love','A'=>'Affection','M'=>'Marriage','E'=>'Enemy','S'=>'Sister','');
    $names = str_split($name1 . $name2);
    $values = array_count_values($names);
    foreach ($values as $k => $val){$letters[$val][] = $k;}
    $cnt = count($letters[1]);
    $ndx = 6;
    $loop = 7;
    while($loop-- > 2){
      $ndx = $matrix[$loop][($cnt + $ndx) %$loop ] ;
      $flames[0] = $flames[$ndx--];
      $flames = array_values(array_unique($flames));
    }


    echo "\n<p>Result: " . $flame[$flames[1]] . '</p>';
```

Notes:

```
$flames = str_split(' FLAMES');
```

Equivalent of

```
array(' ','F','L','A','M','W','S')
```

The `Matrix array` is to change the value where the index pointer (`$ndx`) is equal to zero.

The `$flame` array is to convert the last Letter to the Result Term.

`str_split`, makes an array out of the string, one character per array element.

```
$names = str_split($name1 . $name2);
```

`array_count_values` get the count of each letter.

```
$values = array_count_values($names);
```

This creates a mufti-dimentional array, where the letter count is the key.
letter[1] holds a the unique letters (count [1]).

```
foreach ($values as $k => $val){$letters[$val][] = $k;}
```

Then count the number of unique letters.

```
 $cnt = count($letters[1]);
```

This finds the letter to eliminate, then puts that character in array element 0

```
  $ndx = $matrix[$loop][($cnt + $ndx) %$loop ] ;
  $flames[0] = $flames[$ndx--];
```

Then array_unique eliminates the letter that matches element [0]

array_values renumber the keys from 0 to the number of letters left.

```
  $flames = array_values(array_unique($flames));
```

Comment: so what i need to change?

Comment: Change $flame[$diff] to just $flame or a different variable name or everywhere else refer to $fame as an array.  Like $flame[0].

Comment: i tried but it dint work. can u paste the new code with the changes you are referring?

Comment: I have no idea what the flames game is.  But I am fairly sure you have more problems than just that.  You would need to explain exactly how the game works.

Comment: I re-wrote the code from scratch.  With no IF or ELSE control structures.